# Typeorm driverError: error: syntax error at end of input

Tags: typeorm

I have this code

```
  let anuncios = await anuncioRepository.find({relations: {produto: true}});
```

my models

```
 @Entity({name: 'anuncio_mercado_livre'})
export class AnuncioMercadoLivre {

 
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id:number;

    @Column({name: 'id_produto'})
    idProduto:number;

    @Column({name: 'id_item'})
    idItem:number;

    @Column({nullable: true})
    status: number;

    @Column()
    tipo_envio:number;

    @OneToMany((type) => Produto, (produto) => produto.anuncioMercadoLivre)
    @JoinColumn({name: 'id_produto', foreignKeyConstraintName: 'id'})
    produto: Produto;
    
}
```

The other one

```
     @Entity({name: 'produto'})
export class Produto {

 
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id:number;

    @Column()
    nome:string;

    @Column()
    preco:number;

   
    @Column({nullable: true})
    isbn:string;

    @Column()
    gtin:string;

    @Column()
    sku:string;

    @Column({nullable: true})
    ncm:string;

    @Column()
    descricao:string;

    @Column({name: 'tempo_garantia'})
    tempoGarantia: number;

    @Column()
    estoque:number;


    @Column()
    estado:number;

    @Column({nullable: true})
    mpn:string;

    @Column({nullable : true})
    ean:string;

    @Column()
    peso:number;

    @Column()
    largura:number;

 
    @Column()
    comprimento:number;

    @Column()
    altura:number;

    @Column({name: 'link_video', nullable: true})
    linkVideo:string;


    @Column()
    categoria:number;

    @Column({name: 'id_marca'})
    idMarca:number;

    @Column({name: 'foto_1'})
    foto1:string;

    @Column({name: 'foto_2', nullable: true})
    foto2:string;

    @Column({name: 'foto_3', nullable: true})
    foto3:string;

    @Column({name: 'foto_4', nullable: true})
    foto4:string;


    @Column({name: 'foto_5', nullable: true})
    foto5:string;

    @Column({name: 'foto_6', nullable: true})
    foto6:string;

    @Column({name: 'foto_7', nullable: true})
    foto7:string;

    @Column({name: 'foto_8', nullable: true})
    foto8:string;
 
    

    @OneToMany((type) => Variacao, (variacao) => variacao.produto)
    variacoes: Array<Variacao>


    @OneToMany((type) => AnuncioMercadoLivre, (anuncioMercadoLivre) => anuncioMercadoLivre.produto)
    @JoinColumn({name: 'id', foreignKeyConstraintName: 'id_produto'})

    anuncioMercadoLivre: AnuncioMercadoLivre

}
```

Comment: I just found my mistake. It's one to one. The error is so misleading. I also messed up the relations. Anyone with this error check the relationship.